# post message from android to AWS SNS topic

Tags: android

I have an app where user can type a message. On load, the application should make an API call to get the word of the day from dictionary.com.  When the user types in that word,

Post the existing text entered by the user to an AWS SNS topic.  If the user has entered a name, include the name in the message.  How can i do that

Comment: You want to send message to AWS topic??

Comment: yes. i want to do that

Comment: let me share the code with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all have your **AWS** credentials, from console

```
 // AWS Iot CLI describe-endpoint call returns: XXXXXXXXXX.iot.<region>.amazonaws.com
private static final String CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT = "Your Specific End Point here";
// Cognito pool ID. For this app, pool needs to be unauthenticated pool with
// AWS IoT permissions.
private static final String COGNITO_POOL_ID = "Your Pool id here e.g us-west-2:7eed0766-71bb-4802";
// Name of the AWS IoT policy to attach to a newly created certificate
private static final String AWS_IOT_POLICY_NAME = "iotPubSub";

// Region of AWS IoT
private static final Regions MY_REGION = Regions.US_WEST_2;
// Filename of KeyStore file on the filesystem
private static final String KEYSTORE_NAME = "iot_keystore";
// Password for the private key in the KeyStore
private static final String KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "password";
// Certificate and key aliases in the KeyStore
private static final String CERTIFICATE_ID = "default";
```

Then in `onCreate()`

```
credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(), // context
                COGNITO_POOL_ID, // Identity Pool ID
                MY_REGION // Region
        );

        Region region = Region.getRegion(MY_REGION);

        // MQTT Client
        mqttManager = new AWSIotMqttManager(clientId, CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT);

        // Set keepalive to 10 seconds.  Will recognize disconnects more quickly but will also send
        // MQTT pings every 10 seconds.
        mqttManager.setKeepAlive(10);
  AWSIotMqttLastWillAndTestament lwt = new 
  AWSIotMqttLastWillAndTestament("my/lwt/topic",
                "Android client lost connection", AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0);
        mqttManager.setMqttLastWillAndTestament(lwt);

        // IoT Client (for creation of certificate if needed) 0316 5533564 873459
        mIotAndroidClient.setRegion(region);

        keystorePath = getFilesDir().getPath();
```

Now simple make a call with your topic name, Complete code can be found in [github](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSub), It also explains how to get credentials if you have any problem finding them in your console.

Hope this helps